# debugging a perl assignment

Tags: regex, perl

I should explain as background to this question that I don't know any Perl, and have a violent allergy to regular expressions
(we all have our weaknesses). I'm trying to figure out why a Perl program won't accept the data I'm feeding it. I don't need to understand this program in any depth - I'm just doing a timing comparison.

Consider this assignment statement:

```
($sample_ls_id) = $sample_ls_id =~ /:\w\w(\d+):/;
```

If I understand this correctly, it is checking if `sample_ls_id` matches some regex, and if so, assigning the entire string, or something like that.

However, I don't understand how this works.
According to the documentation, namely [`perldoc perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html), which I looked at briefly

```
$sample_ls_id =~ /:\w\w(\d+):/
```

just returns true or false if there is a match.

The strings I'm trying to match look like

```
1000    10      0       0       1        urn:lsid:dcc.hapmap.org:Individual:CEPH1000.10:1        urn:lsid:dcc.hapmap.org:Sample:SAMPLE1:1
```

This fails with the error

```
Use of uninitialized value $sample_ls_id in concatenation (.) or string
at database/populate/family.pl line 38, <INPUT> line 1.
```

Line 38 is

```
print OUTPUT "$sample_ls_id\t$family_ped_id\t$individual_ped_id\t$father_ped_id\t$mother_ped_id\t$sex\t$created_by\t$population_code\n";
```

See the complete script below. However, the apparently very similar string

```
1420    9       0       0       1       urn:lsid:dcc.hapmap.org:Individual:CEPH1420.09:1  urn:lsid:dcc.hapmap.org:Sample:NA12003:1
```

seems to pass.

For context, the entire piece of code is:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

my $input_file = "data/family_ceu.txt";
my $output_file = "sql/family_ceu.sql";
my $population_code = "CEU";

GetOptions ('i=s' => \$input_file,
            'o=s' => \$output_file,
            'p=s' => \$population_code
            );

usagecheck();

my $created_by = 'gwas_analyzer';

print "Creating SQL file for inserting family data from $input_file\n";

open (INPUT, "< $input_file");
open (OUTPUT, "> $output_file");

print OUTPUT "INSERT INTO population (population_code, private) VALUES ('$population_code', 'f');\n";
print OUTPUT "COPY family (ls_id, family_ped_id, individual_ped_id, father_ped_id, mother_ped_id, sex, created_by, population_code) FROM stdin;                      
";

while (my $line = <INPUT>)
{
    chomp $line;

    #Skip any comment lines 
    next if($line =~ /^#/);

    my ($family_ped_id, $individual_ped_id, $father_ped_id, $mother_ped_id, $sex, $individual_ls_id, $sample_ls_id) = split (/\t/, $line);

    ($sample_ls_id) = $sample_ls_id =~ /:\w\w(\d+):/;

    print OUTPUT "$sample_ls_id\t$family_ped_id\t$individual_ped_id\t$father_ped_id\t$mother_ped_id\t$sex\t$created_by\t$population_code\n";
}

print OUTPUT "\\.\n";
close OUTPUT;

sub usagecheck
{
    if (!$input_file || !$output_file || !$population_code)
    {
        print "Missing argument (see required arguments below):\n";
        usage();
        exit;
    }
}

sub usage
{
    print "perl family.pl -i <input file> -o <output file> -p <population code>\n";
}
```

I'm sure this is a very simple question if you know regexes and Perl.

Comment: What is the goal of sample_ls_id? are you simply trying to capture the \d+ and store it in sample_ls_id? What do you expect sample_ls_id to hold if there is no match?

Comment: @onaclov2000: I believe so. It gets written to a file eventually. Well, not me, but the authors of this code. :-)

Comment: you're splitting on tabs, but your example input isn't tab delimited, so this is a tad confusing, could you update?

Comment: My example input isn't the entire line that is being split, only the last element. I'll post the entire line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `$sample_ls_id = 'urn:lsid:dcc.hapmap.org:Sample:SAMPLE1:1';`

The regular expression '/:\w\w(\d+):/;' fails. This regular expression would pass when the string has a colon ':' followed by a "word" character '\w',
another "word" character '\w' followed by one or more digits '\d+' and a colon ':'.

When `$sample_ls_id = 'urn:lsid:dcc.hapmap.org:Sample:NA12003:1';`

The regular expression '/:\w\w(\d+):/;' finds its match in 
':NA12003:'. ( colon, 2 word characters, digits and a colon ).

```
my $sample_id = 'urn:lsid:dcc.hapmap.org:Sample:NA12003:1'
($sample_ls_id) = $sample_ls_id =~ /:\w\w(\d+):/;
```

'( $sample_ls_id )' captures the '(\d+)' portion of the match ( also stored in $1 ), which in this case would be 12003.

You were getting an error with the earlier example, because the regular expression fails and leaves '($sample_ls_id)' undefined.

Comment: I see. So the problem is that my string in this case `SAMPLE` is not two characters long? This is pretty barmy, but I didn't write this code. I'd appreciate confirmation that my understanding is correct. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, thats right. If you want ':SAMPLE1:' to be matched and capture '1', then you can change your regex to - /:\w+(\d+):/.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In a list context, such as an assignment to `($sample_ls_id)`, `=~` returns a list of the captures. It saves you extracting `$1` etc. in a separate statement.

Comment: Thanks, haven't done that before, I'm wondering if the problem is so much with the regex....the error points to somewhere before the regex it looks like

Comment: In a list context, when there are capturing parentheses.  When there aren't, it returns () or 1 for success or failure.

Answer (score 0):

Rather then storing the string back into itself per se, just use the capture.
\d is held by $1, so simply change your code to something like this:

```
$sample_ls_id =~ /:\w\w(\d+):/; # no letters before implies "match"
$sample_ls_id = $1; # I assume that $1 will be empty if no match, I'm not 100% on this.
```

I don't know why you're getting the error you're getting, but it seems like your code would make more sense like the above.

It could have something do do with if you're input doesn't have that last element (I.E. you have A:B:C but you need A:B:C:D to store D in the sample ls id, if D is missing then it's never initialized and then the regex wouldn't make sense.)

Also We don't have all the code (line 38 looks like it corresponds to the first line in your while loop), if you post more that might help.

Comment: Sure. I can post the entire Perl script in question, if it would help. And I'm not the author of this code, I'm just trying to make sense of it. I don't know any Perl.

Comment: You are 100% wrong on that :-)  $1 will contain some stale left-over value from a previous match that _did_ succeed. "You should never use the dollar-digit variables unless you have first tested that the match succeeded". If the match fails, you will have inserted a hard-to-find bug. The original construct (match in list context) is a way to avoid this problem. If the match fails, then it will return the empty list, and $sample_ls_id will contain undef.

Comment: Thanks, I usually use "if ($blah =~ m/et(c)/){} so I haven't ran across using the $1 outside of that context. I'll have to keep that in mind in the future!